# Assign point_dist with the distance between point (x1, y1) and point (x2, y2). The calculation is: Distance = SquareRootOf( (x2 - x1)2 + (y2 - y1)2 )

Tags: variables, scripting

Assign point_dist with the distance between point (x1, y1) and point (x2, y2). The calculation is: Distance = SquareRootOf( (x2 - x1)2 + (y2 - y1)2 ).

Sample output with inputs: 1.0 2.0 1.0 5.0
Points distance: 3.0

```
point_dist = math.sqrt(x2 - x1) * 3.0 (y2 - y1) * 3.0)
```

Comment: I got the first portion correct, but I can't get the second portion correct

Comment: import math

point_dist = 0.0

x1 = float(input())
y1 = float(input())
x2 = float(input())
y2 = float(input())

point_dist = math.sqrt( x2 - x1) * 3.0 + ( y2 - y1) * 3.0

print('Points distance:', point_dist)

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: in the above main topic it has what needs to be done below that is what I did, but I am missing something, but I am stuck.

Comment: Note that the terms (x2-x1) and (y2-y1) are *squared* (there should be a *superscript* 2 in the text), while you seem to be multiplying by 3. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
point_dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2.0 +(y2 - y1) ** 2.0)
```

you were very close just a few minor changes

Answer (score 0):

```
pointsDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1) , 2.0) +Math.pow((y2 - y1) , 2.0));
```

Try this for Java.

Answer (score 0):

So remember that you can break down the equation like this:

```
total_1 = x2 - x1
total_2 = y2 - y1
```

This worked for me